# Gold forensics - can gold's source mine be determined?

Tags: nuclear-physics, metals

A lot of [gold was moved from it source in the west to Europe and other world powers](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/44148/6961) in the 16th and following centuries and I was curious if such gold artifacts could be tied to their source or not.

In the 2010 New Scientist article, [Nuclear bomb debris holds clues to who planted it](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn19699-nuclear-bomb-debris-holds-clues-to-who-planted-it/) this statement is made, but the link to the reference no longer works:

> In 2009, researchers from the Institute for Transuranium Elements in Karlsruhe, Germany, showed that when smuggled nuclear material is intercepted, its source can be deduced from details of its composition.

Can the processes used in nuclear forensics be used on gold from this era?

Comment: Gold has only one stable isotope, so I do not quite see how. Maybe on the basis of impurities.

Comment: @Pieter - impurities might help, but gold is also often reworked which could confuse things. As you noted, isotope variation is right out.  Minerals such as turquoise are often attributed to mines in specific areas based on composition variation, but I think gold would be hard to impossible.

Comment: I agree with @JonCuster. There might be a difference in isotope composition of gold depending on its origin.

Comment: @freecharly - Au has one stable isotope, so you really would be looking at impurities. The impurities will depend on the original ire body, but also any further processing. That is why it is doable for minerals, since you don’t melt them down and refine them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm hoping that physics has a solution, since the nuclear forensics is based on a physics paper, I'm hoping there's a similar method for gold.  Are there changes to the question that would make it fit this site better?  If so, please consider editing it.

Comment: @JonCuster You are right, as Au has only one stable isotope and the unstable ones have a very short half-life, the impurity composition is the only possible way to get some information on the origin. Even very small   impurity isotope concentrations can be determined with a mass spectrometer.

Comment: @JonCuster - I think you should put your comment about the impurity composition as an answer! The impurity composition seems to be the only promising way to identify the origin of different Au samples.

Answer (score 1):

As @pieter pointed out, Gold has only one stable isotope.  There are radioactive isotopes but these are very short lived.  The longest half life for one of these is 186.09 *days* for Au-195.

Au-195 decays by Beta decay, meaning it will transform into the most common stable isotope of Platinum.

What does that mean in terms of how many many of these Au-195 atoms we can expect to find in a lump of Gold ?

Well one mole of Gold has about $6\times 10^{23}$ atoms (that's a mass of about 197 grammes).

Let's say we start out with 50% Au-195.  Every 186 days the amount halves.  Probably the gold has been in the ground at least a thousand years.  How much Au-195 have we left ?  About 1963 half lives have passed in 1000 years and that means we have about $2^{-1963}$ of our Au-195 left.  That's a really small number and is about $1.5\times 10^{-591}$ which means we'll have about $4.4\times 10^{-568}$ Au-195 atoms left (or to be a little less impractical - none).

We'll have lots of Platinum.  But what will happen the gold when it's taken from the ground ?  Melted down and the platinum thrown away as being worthless, I dare say. :-)  Well, we won't be seeing any platinum either.

But we're not even going to see those Gold and Platinum mixtures (of that type).  What would have happened is that the Gold was created well before the Earth formed - that's 4.5 billion years.  And all the Au-195 was created then as well.  No more would be created after that.  And 4.5 billion years is a an awful lot of Au-195 half lives, so no Au-195 would survive long enough even to exist in the early Earth.  It would have decayed long before our planet even formed.

So basically no other isotopes of Gold ever made it "into the mix" to form Gold deposits on Earth, just good old stable (!) Au-197.

Comment: Wait, if gold-195 is going for USD1,330 per ounce and platinum is at USD1,553--that's an 8 percent return over 6 months. Not bad: it beats the market.

Comment: Are any other methods used for nuclear forensics, or is it all about the isotopes?

Comment: You should also consider that, e.g., due to different diffusion speeds of isotopes, also the composition in stable isotopes might depend on the way it has accumulated or been processed.

Comment: As Au has only one stable isotope, the only promising way to get some information about the origin of a Au sample seems to be its impurity composition! See the comment by @JonCuster.

Answer (score 1):

Smuggled nuclear materials are much easier. They are radioactive by themselves. A high-resolution gamma spectrum gives a lot of information about the ratios of different isotopes of for example uranium and plutonium. The amount of decay products gives dating information.

This cannot be done with gold. One can make gold radioactive by neutron activation, but that does not give information about the mine of origin. Gold has only one stable isotope.

One can try neutron-activation analysis of other elements in the gold alloy, but this is not normally conclusive.

There are non-nuclear techniques to determine chemical composition. One can also measure isotope composition with mass spectrometry (but this only works for other elements in the alloy).

Gold is so often reprocessed that I would not expect consistent results. Best one can do is probably to expose forgeries.

Answer (score 1):

Impurity analysis would be the only way to do this.

Note that impurities in the lead used by the Romans to make their plumbing allows researchers to trace it back to the specific mine in Spain where the ore was originally extracted in the following way: Since the ore smelting process produced a significant plume of particulate smoke from the ore and since the prevailing winds blew that smoke up towards Greenland, researchers can dig down through the annual ice layers on the Greenland ice cap and extract from it thin layers of microspherules of burnt ore and assign a firm date to each deposit based on its position in the ice column. microanalysis of the spherules reveals their composition and therefore the location of the specific mine from which the ore originated can be identified, as well as the specific years during which that mine was active.

Comment: Indeed. It works with lead because it has has four stable isotopes.

Comment: @pieter, the article I read on that did not use isotopic analysis- they looked for contaminant metals present in trace amounts mixed into the lead as the "fingerprint". I do not remember what those tramp metals were though. -Niels